# unix process set of files with timestamp at once

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

We get set of files like (TEMP1_12172014.txt, TEMP2_12172014.txt, TEMP3_12172014.txt) as one set and (TEMP1_12182014.txt,TEMP2_12182014.txt ,TEMP3_12182014.txt) .

All the 6 files are at one location: /home/wauser/tempfiles

i have to process TEMP1,TEMP2 and TEMP3 at a once based on time stamp. Processing has to be done one set after other. Once first set processing is completed, remove that set from the location and process the next set.

please help in finding a way to execute these files using unix script.

Update: we have to just copy one set of files from /home/wauser/tempfiles to /home/wauser/tempprocessfiles

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Observation: using the date format 20141217 (20141218) means that the files with the same prefix sort in date order with a plain sort.

Comment: Can you determine easily which groups of files are or should be present? Do they have to be processed in date order?

Comment: files related to one date have to be processed at once.

Comment: Do you have a record of which dates should be processed, or do you have to determine that from the files present?  You say 'copy one set of files to ...'; does that mean that the originals stay behind, or do you mean 'move' rather than 'copy'?

Comment: no , we dont have record of which set of files to process. We can process any set of files. Just that one set of files has to be procesed at a time. Move the file instead of copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
source="/home/wauser/tmpfiles"
target="/home/wauser/tempprocessfiles"

cd "$source" || exit 1

ls TEMP[0-9]_[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]20[0-9][0-9].txt 2>/dev/null |
sed 's/TEMP._\([01][0-9][0-3][0-9]20[0-9][0-9]\)\.txt/\1/' |
sort -u |
sed 1q |
while read date
do
    mv TEMP[0-9]_${date}.txt "$target"
done
```

Using `ls` is a bit debatable, but if the file names are controlled as they seem to be, you won't run into problems with unexpected characters in the names -- spaces and newlines in file names wreak havoc on scripts, but the names described explicitly don't include spaces etc.

The script changes directory to the source directory (or exits; the `cd` command would generate an error message if it fails).  It generates a list of possible dates from the file names that match the template, which is moderately constrained to recognized semi-plausible dates (but it allows the the 39th day of the 19th month; it isn't really validating the dates).  From that list, it chooses the one that sorts earliest.  That means it will select the 1st of December before the 30th of November.  If you used dates in the format YYYYMMDD, then the first entry listed would be the oldest date.  You can fix it if you want to with a more complex sort criterion:

```
sort -u -k 1.5,1.9 -k 1.3,1.4 -k 1.1,1.2
```

The 'while' loop is also arguably redundant; you could replace it with `(read date; mv TEMP[0-9]_${data}.txt "$target")` or thereabouts.  You could then omit the `sed 1q` part of the pipeline; only the first line will be read.